# Blank Page and Alignment Issues in SSRS Report

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to generate a report in SSRS BIDS  2008 and export it to PDF format in my applicaiton.  I have a main report with 20+ sub reports. On Exporting to PDF I am getting multiple blank pages in between.​

I have googled up a few things like setting the Page Width, Margins, Keepto​gether and Remove White Space. But still I am facing the issue.

Please help.

Comment: Do you get these blank pages when you preview the report? If so, check all your PageBreak property values. If not, it's a conversion issue that is not easy to troubleshoot.

Comment: No i don't have the issue while previewing the report in the BIDS. But when I save it as PDF, the blank pages starts appearing.

Comment: That sounds like the report is "too big" and it spills over to another page, could be a n issue with your margins, try setting your margins at 0 and export to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your Sub Report `page size` are not even, ensure that all are using the same `page size` E.g.: if you use Letter format as `page size` ensure all the Sub Report have the same Letter format. Also your Main report also must use the same `page size`. Hope this helps!